# add element to iterable in java

Tags: java, addition, iterable

I have the following code:

```
public class Router {
  private Iterable<Route> routes;

  public Router(Iterable<Route> routes) {
    this.routes = routes;
  }
  public void addRoute(Route route) {
    routes.add(route);\\problem is here
  }
}
```

I highlighted the line which is not working. Here I try to add a new object to the routes. In main file routes are:

```
public class RouterMain 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IllegalArgumentException 
    {
        List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
        Router router = new Router(routes);
    }
}
```

The task is to add an object in iterable object in `Router` class. As I understood `Iterable` can iterate, not add something. So what should I do, convert routes in `Router` class to a `List`, add an element and go back?

Comment: An iterable is usually used to walk through a collection so I don't know if this is even possible or why you'd want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add to it you could create a new list and add all the current elements to that list and then just add the object you would like after e.g

```
public class Router {
  private Iterable<Route> routes;

  public Router(Iterable<Route> routes) {
    this.routes = routes;
  }
  public void addRoute(Route route) {

    //create new list
    ArrayList<Route> myList = new ArrayList<Route>();

    //iterate through current objects and add them to new list
    Iterator<Route> routeIterator = routes.iterator();
    while(routeIterator.hasNext()){
        myList.add(routeIterator.next());
    }


    //add object you would like to the list
    myList.add(route);

  }
}
```

Comment: Then you could return the list and do what ever you like with it

Comment: @ovod This code is wrong. `while(routes.iterator().hasNext())` will cause an infinite loop, since each time you call routes.iterator(), you get a new Iterator, and `routes.iterator().next()` will always return the first Route returned by the Iterator.

Comment: FIX:  
    //create iterator
    Iterator itr = routes.iterator();
    
    //iterate through current objects and add them to new list
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        myList.add(itr.next());
    }

Answer (score 7):

`Iterable<Router>` is used to enable iterating over the `Router` elements contained in your class. It is not a Collection, though many collections implement this interface. It doesn't have the `add` method. It only has a method that returns an `Iterator<Router>`.

You should use some Collection (List, Set, etc...) to store your routes. Those collections have `add` method.

```
public class Router {
  private List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();

  public Router(Iterable<Route> routes) {
    for (Route route : routes)
      this.routes.add(route);
  }

}
```

Comment: I undestand it))) But it is my hometask. My class gets iterable object and my task is to add something to it. So I need to convert it to collection and again back?

Comment: @ovod You can iterate over the Iterator that you can obtain from the input Iterable. Then you can store the elements in any Collection you wish.

Comment: @ovod See my code sample. You can use the enhanced for loop to iterate over the elements of the input iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Iterable doesn't has the method add. Maybe you need an AbstractCollection

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html

Answer (score 0):

`Iterable` is a type which is mostly used in loops and utility functions - you should avoid it in general. I suggest to change the constructor to `Router(Collection<Route> routes)` and use the `Collection` interface internally. That way, you can use almost any collection type (sets, and lists).

For additional safety, make a copy of the collection - then you can't be hurt by someone making changes to the collection outside of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List` interface instead of `Iterable`. It has a method `listIterator`. Which returnes an instance of `ListIterator`. In this interface you can both add and remove items. Iterable does not look to fit in your task.